# retrieving value from array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

print_r($array) results
I retrieved some values from database and got the following result while using print_r:

```
Array
(
    [122] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => Tony Hutson
            [p_image] => profile_image/profile_61323166474.jpg
            [pid] => 42
            [sid] => 122
            [stitle] => sfcxdggf
            [audio] => audio_file/audio_61324302202.mp3
            [s_description] => ?mnlmkl bvnbmnmmn, bnbmn 
            [s_image] => sermon_image/image_41324302202.jpg
        )

    [count] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
        )
)
```

How can I retrieve the value of count?

Comment: `var_export` produces valid PHP, which is more useful than the output of `print_r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $array['count']['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
echo $array['count']['count'];
```

Comment: The person ([profile here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/696364/rikesh-shah)), who answered this question one minute before you, giving exact same (identical) code as solution. That person deleted his/her answer some minutes after that, you left your answer and now you corrected it. Thanks for correction and good luck!